# Virtual memory exhausted error

Tags: makefile

I'm using gnu make 3.80 and I got the following error. I have 4 gigs of RAM and about 5.6 gigs of swap.

```
make[1]: *** virtual memory exhausted.  Stop.
```

I got to work this on make 3.80. Installing 3.81 is not an option for me. Are there any hacks to overcome this issue?

Comment: How can we help you without knowing anything about your makefile?

Comment: I don't think it is telling you to get more memory. There must be a problem with the makefile.

Comment: Can you share the output of "ulimit -a" with us?

Answer (score 0):

Are you including generated dependency files from another version of make?

---

Just experienced this error as well trying to support an older version of make (3.80) for some legacy code. My make system was including dependency files in a manner such as:

```
-include $(myDependencies)
```

Problem was, my dependency files were already generated when I built the program with make 4.0. By performing a clean and rebuilding again, I was able to build successfully. I'm under the assuming the new make version adds complexity to the dependency file that the old version of make cannot handle well.